# Count records sea orm

Tags: rust, sea-orm

I'm looking for a way to count all the records found by a query. I can see there is a [count](https://docs.rs/sea-orm/0.9.3/sea_orm/entity/prelude/struct.Select.html#method.count) function but I'm not entirely sure how to deal with the output to get a number type out.

I have something similar to

```
entity::table_name::Entity::find().count(&db);
```

which returns a `Pin<Box<dyn Future + Send<Output = Result<usize, DbErr>>>>`

I'm just looking to get a number out. Am I on the right track here? What would be the simplest way to get the count?

Comment: Probably `.await` and then have the `Result`.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze You're right, that massively simplifies it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the count as a usize is as simple as

```
entity::entity_name::Entity::find().count(&db).await.unwrap();
```

Where entity_name is the name of your table/entity.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, EnumIter, DeriveColumn)]
enum Counter {
    Count,
}

entity::table_name::Entity::find()
    .select_only()
    .column_as(Expr::col(entity::table_name::Column::Id).count(), "count")
    .into_values::<_, Counter>()
    .one(&db)
    .await
```

This looks however a bit complicated